# Why composer fails to set CodeSniffer in a clone of a Magento2 project?

Tags: php, docker, magento, composer-php, ddev

I cloned a repo through bitbucket, it's a Magento2 project.

Here's some specifics:

- I'm using `ddev` along with `docker` in a **Windows** environment.
- I've used **Ubuntu v18.04**
- **php v7.4.1**
- **composer v2**

Now, I'm able to run `ddev start` and it returns me three *URLs* to visit the website.

But when I try to reach each one of them there's this error:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/stores.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 82

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/stores.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/vendor/deployer/recipes') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 82
```

So I tried to run `composer install` both from the shell (`ddev ssh`) and outside of it, to no success.

I tried to delete `vendor` folder and re-run `composer install`, to no success.

Also, everytime I run `composer install` it fails to set **CodeSniffer** as shown below:

```
Generating autoload files
137 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config
```

As I seem to understand, the problem is in this **autoload_real.php** file inside *vendor/composer/* folder:

```
<?php

// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer

class ComposerAutoloaderInit95a846f5f47c0550ba8f462ebc5cc61f
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
     */
    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        require __DIR__ . '/platform_check.php';

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit95a846f5f47c0550ba8f462ebc5cc61f', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(\dirname(\dirname(__FILE__)));
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit95a846f5f47c0550ba8f462ebc5cc61f', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $includePaths = require __DIR__ . '/include_paths.php';
        $includePaths[] = get_include_path();
        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePaths));

        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit95a846f5f47c0550ba8f462ebc5cc61f::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            $includeFiles = Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit95a846f5f47c0550ba8f462ebc5cc61f::$files;
        } else {
            $includeFiles = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_files.php';
        }
        foreach ($includeFiles as $fileIdentifier => $file) {
            composerRequire95a846f5f47c0550ba8f462ebc5cc61f($fileIdentifier, $file);
        }

        return $loader;
    }
}

/**
 * @param string $fileIdentifier
 * @param string $file
 * @return void
 */
function composerRequire95a846f5f47c0550ba8f462ebc5cc61f($fileIdentifier, $file)
{
    if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
        $GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;

        require $file;
    }
}
```

The last comand I've tried is `composer dump-autoload` but the result is the same.

So I need to get rid of that error in the webpage, to be able to see it correctly, and be able to set CodeSniffer in some way.

Why this error, and how could I resolve it?

If anyone can help on this, it would be awesome. Thanks guys.

Also, I've already tried to install **CodeSniffer** globally, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: When you say composer install doesn't work - what do you get - errors or just nothing installed?

Comment: I get packages installed, but it always fails to set CodeSniffer. It'n not returning errors, but I still cannot see the page.

Comment: I've said "no success" cause even if packages are being installed I'm still stucked. I dont' know if the problem is **CodeSniffer** or something in that **autoload_real.php** file

Comment: Please add all appropriate error messages, in full, as text. Those images are unreadable on mobile, useless for anyone visually impaired, and mean that future users with the same error won't find your question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated the question with readable text.

Comment: Does the file exist, /var/www/html/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/stores.php ? If not... that's the issue. It's certainly possible that your composer.json doesn't build a working system.

Comment: No I've checked in *app/etc/* and there's no `stores.php` file. How can I solve this issue about composer.json? Also I've just re-deleted the *vendor* folder and re-run `composer install` to have the same issue about **CodeSniffer** and this `GrumPHP can not sniff your commits! (invalid-exit-code)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the `html` directory run `vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show`
If `installed_paths` is not listed, or is incorrect run the following:

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
```

If the above still doesn't work, here is a more in-depth answer posted in the magento exchange: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/371402/113483